# Comparing two strings without using strcmp

Tags: c++

This is my question:
Write a function name `compareStrings(char * str1, char * str1, int i=0)`, which returns decides whether 
the two received string are equal or not. The third parameter decides whether to take case 
sensitiveness while comparing strings: 0 means case sensitive, otherwise case sensitive.

- The function returns 0 if two strings are equal
- Returns 1 if str1 > str2
- Returns -1 if str1 < str2.

Example:

- `compareStrings( “apple”, “Apple” )` returns 1
- `compareStrings( “apple a day keeps the doctor away”, “apple are good for health” )` returns -1

This code I have done yet but it is not comparing all Ascii's. According to me I must put all Ascii's checks but it would be so long 
Please tell me any other logic regarding this Question.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int compareStrings(char * str1, char * str2);
int main()
{
    char str1[]="apple";
    char str2[]="Apple";
    int ret;
    ret=compareStrings(str1,str2);
    if(ret==0)
        cout<<"Both strings are equal"<<endl;
    else if(ret==1)
        cout<<"string 1 is bigger than 2"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"string 1 is lower than 2"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int compareStrings(char * str1, char * str2)
{
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        if(str1[i]==str2[i])
            return 0;
        else if(str1[i] >= 'A' && str1[i] <= 'Z' &&str2[i] <='a' && str2[i]<='z')
            return -1;
        else if(str2[i] >= 'A' && str2[i] <= 'Z' &&str1[i] <='a' && str1[i]<='z')
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the first character is equal you return 0 without checking the rest of the string.  You probably shouldn't hardcode the comparison to 20 characters since neither of your strings is 20 characters long.  You'd want to get the length first.

Comment: Your examples are bad practice because you point to a string literal with `char *` and not `const char *`

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int getLen(char*s);
int main()
{
 int len;
 char s[]="we are muslims";
 len=getLen(s);
 cout<<len<<endl;
  return 0;
}
 
int getLen(char*s)
{
 int count =0;
 while(*s!='\0')
 {
  count++;
  s++;
 }
 return count;
}

Comment: @tayyibahalauddin wtf

Comment: You don't really need to retrieve the string lengths before comparing the strings. That is just wasted overhead. Simply start looping, comparing each character as needed.  When a difference is detected, return -1/1 accordingly. When one of the strings reaches its null terminator, check if the other string also reached its null terminator at the same time, and if so then return 0, otherwise return -1/1 accordingly.

Comment: I assume this is a school assignment. It's a pity they don't allow you to use `std::string` but just disallow the use of its `operator==` and some other handy bits for the exercise. Then you get the incidental benefits of `std::string` but still the challenge of the exercise.

Comment: If I would put this in my code ,size would be strings length.but Iogic would be still incorrect

Comment: Neil Kirk I have not learned std::string concept yet in school

Comment: @NeilKirk: it is a shame the assignment does not allow the use of `strcmp()` and `stricmp()`, otherwise the function could be implemented as simply `return (i != 0) ? strcmp(str1, str2) : stricmp(str1, str2);`

Comment: This question must be solved without strcmp,isupper,islower etc. Just the challenge is do this with simple pf concept but how

Comment: You have a typo at the end, when you check that one character is uppercase and the other is lowercase: `else if(str1[i] >= 'A' && str1[i] <= 'Z' &&str2[i] <='a' && str2[i]<='z')` should be `else if(str1[i] >= 'A' && str1[i] <= 'Z' &&str2[i] >='a' && str2[i]<='z')`, that is, str2 must be greater than a, not less. The same goes for the check on str1 two lines below it.

Comment: but this would not compare spaces n other Ascii's

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems with the code as shown.  I'm ignoring the fact that you aren't using C++ `std::string` type, though that is another issue.

1. You only compare the first twenty characters of the strings.

   - What happens if the strings are longer?
   - What is the return value from the function if the loop ends?
2. You compare the first twenty characters of the strings even if the strings are shorter.
3. You return 0 on the first character that's the same.
4. You return -1 if the current character in the first string is upper-case and the current character in the second is lower-case, regardless of whether the case-sensitivity flag is set or whether the letters are equivalent.
5. Similarly you return +1 for the converse condition.
6. You don't use the `isalpha()`, `isupper()`, `islower()` macros (prefixed with `std::` from `<cctype>` or equivalent functions.
7. You don't recognize that if one string contains a `7` and the other a `9`, you should come to a decision.
8. Since the comparison function is not supposed to modify either string, the function prototype should use `const char *` arguments.

Etc.

You will need to rethink your code rather carefully.  Ignore case-insensitivity until you have case-sensitive comparisons working correctly.  Then you can modify it to handle case-insensitive comparisons too.

Comment: I have to do this without cctype library

Comment: @tayyibahalauddin: Hi; the code in a comment is unreadable.  The `*` characters get used for italics, etc.  Use back-quotes around the code, but it would be better to update the question with the code and your auxilliary question — whatever it is.  Please remove your comments — here and under the question proper — and update the question with what you intend to add/ask.

Comment: @tayyibahalauddin: If you must work without the `<cctype>` header (it is a _header_, not a _library_), say so in the question. It is important that we know all the petty restrictions so that we don't break the rules you're supposed to follow. What are you allowed to assume about the code sets you're working with? Could it be EBCDIC whch has non-alpha characters encoded in the middle of the alphabet? Is it pure (7-bit) ASCII, so we don't have to worry about accented alphabetic characters and there is a simple transform between upper-case and lower-case? These things are important, sadly.

Comment: sir that is length function ,

Comment: I do not have high hopes for this question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Nor me, really.  I'm hoping it will be educational on how to think, but maybe that's being optimistic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Sadly I'm afraid I suspect so.

Comment: @tayyibahalauddin: Note that the basic comparison algorithm should be: (1) while the current character in each string is the same, if the character is the terminating null return 0 otherwise go to next character in the string; (2) the loop has terminated; the characters are different; return the appropriate value.  Note that the 'is the same' test can be case-sensitive or case-insensitive, but (for the ASCII characters) is fairly simple.  Unless you have a taste for the perverse, you will sort non-alphanumeric characters in code-set order, probably deciding that digits come before letters.

Comment: @tayyibahalauddin: Note too that the test after the loop ends still needs to take into account the case-sensitive vs case-insensitive tests for letters.

Comment: ok let me try,n thanks to all of u.